# Is there a way to configure Azure AD SSO to ignore SP forceAuthn parameter?

Tags: sso, saml, azure, adfs

I am trying to workaround an annoying cloud based SP initiated sign-on parameter, forceAuthn, the SP includes this in their assertion and is set to true. They do this to ensure compliance with some of their other customers and are unwilling to allow this to be configurable. This is flooding my organization with support tickets because it forces them to log back into our Azure AD even when they have a valid session.

I know that Okta allows you to ignore this with "Honor the ForceAuthN" on the app configuration in Okta, but I could not find something like this in Azure AD.